# How to add previous rows of a column in a new column on the same data set?

Tags: r

I have 2 columns, "x" and "y" generated with this code:

```
x = 1:8
y = c(2,7,1,3,5,4,1,2)
data = data.frame(x,y)
```

It look like this:

```
x y
1 2
2 7
3 1
4 3
5 5
6 4
7 1
8 2
```

Now I want to keep adding all the previous rows of "y" into "z".

```
x y z
1 2 2
2 7 9
3 1 10
4 3 13
5 5 18
6 4 22
7 1 23
8 2 25
```

I have tried everything without any luck.

Comment: What are the "previous rows of y?" Where are they coming from? I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: all the top rows

Comment: 'data$z=cumsum(data$y)'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `cumsum`, the cumulative sum function.

```
data$z <- cumsum(data$y)
```

Answer (score 1):

probably not the cleanest way, but this is easy to understand and works well:

```
data$z=NA
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){ 
  if(i==1){
    data[i,'z']=data[i,'y']
  } else{
    data[i,'z']=data[i,'y']+data[i-1,'z']
  }
}
```

Comment: I like Nathan's answer better though. Use that.